# Custom nameserver not resolving

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

My client has a Wordpress.com owned domain name and from the looks of it, you can only change the nameserver on this instead of just pointing the A record.

Currently my server (Centos VPS w/ Parallels Plesk) is not configured with a ns so I ran through tutorials of doing this with NameCheap and Plesk and have not yet been successful:

In Namecheap I setup the "Nameserver Registration" options so that

ns1.kilrizzy.com and ns2.kilrizzy.com point to my vps's IP (I only have 1 IP address)

(After running into trouble I also have A records set for each of these pointing to my server)

In Plesk DNS settings for the domain, I have

```
ns1.kilrizzy.com.   NS  ns1.kilrizzy.com.
ns1.kilrizzy.com.   A   216.224.176.52
ns2.kilrizzy.com.   NS  ns2.kilrizzy.com.
ns2.kilrizzy.com.   A   216.224.176.52
```

Yet, when I apply these nameservers to other domains I still have no luck having them point over. Any help in debugging this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems like your nameservers aren't resolving: http://pastebin.com/BtnLxgPq

Comment: Thanks Nathan, this made me go back and double check I must have removed the A records from namecheap when trying other ideas. When I tracert I'm getting the correct server now, though my domains with this as their nameserver come up as "could not find host"/"unable to resolve target system name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want:

```
kilrizzy.com. NS ns1
kilrizzy.com. NS ns2
ns1 A 216.224.176.52
ns2 A 216.224.176.52
```